# Convert UTC to locale time using timezone ID in MicroPython

Tags: micropython

I have the UTC time string `Mon, 03 Jul 2023 15:13:42 GMT` which I want to convert into local time (without date, e. g. `17:13`) by specifying a timezone ID (e. g. `Europe/Berlin`).

How can I do this in MicroPython?